# How to get Facebook Friend contact number

Tags: android, facebook

I am Working on project where I required to load Facebook friend list's contact number to list-view. is there any way to integrate Facebook API to application in such a way ?? i find email id property but required contact number of friend through this graph API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, start with the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/).

[Here is a demo, for showing a User's friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends/). You should be able to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: thanks for guide but can you clear more about how to get friends contact number ?? is there any attribute ?

Comment: @Nil What is a contact number? There user id?

Comment: @Nil If you want their phone number this guide may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/

You'll need extended permissions for that, probably from each of their friends.

Comment: Contact Number means phone number, is there any other way to get number from Google contact list ?

Comment: in worst case suppose not we able to access phone number but can we access email address?

Comment: @Nil You could get permissions to the users Google contact list when they install your app. Then you can read phone numbers from there. You could even compare contact names to Facebook names to deduce that it's the phone number of that Facebook user.